# How do you apply map to an element of a 2D array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Ruby newbie here... I want to apply Array.map! to an element of a 2D array, but doing something like the example below applies map to every element of the array.

```
array = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0))
array[2].map! { |e| e + 1 }
print array
```

This gives me `[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]` whereas I want something more like `[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Phrogz said you just need to initialize correctly.

Then you can use your methodology

```
 array = Array.new(3){ Array.new(3,0)}
 #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
 array[2].map!{|e| e + 1}
 #=> [1, 1, 1]
 array
 #=> [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to map each, for example:

```
modified = array.map{ |sub| sub.map{ |e| e+1 } }
```

If you want to mutate in-place:

```
array.each{ |sub| sub.map!{ |e| e+1 } }
```

However, you are not creating your initial 2D array correctly. You want:

```
array = Array.new(3){ Array.new(3) }
```

…so that the sub-entries are not shared. See the marked-as-duplicate answer in the comment above for more information.